# Undefined class 'auth.FirebaseAuth'

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
import 'base_auth_repository.dart';

// class AuthRepository {
//   Future<void> login() async {
//     print('attempting login');
//     await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
//     print('logged in');
//     throw Exception('failed log in');
//   }
// }

class AuthRepository extends BaseAuthRepository {
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  Future<void> login() async {
    print('attempting login');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    print('logged in');
    throw Exception('failed log in');
  }

  AuthRepository({auth.FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth})
      : _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Future<auth.User?> signUp({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      final credential = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      final user = credential.user;
      return user;
    } catch (_) {}
  }

  @override
  Stream<auth.User?> get user => _firebaseAuth.userChanges();

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

The error is in auth.FirebaseAuth and is:

> Undefined class 'auth.FirebaseAuth'.
> Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'auth.FirebaseAuth' but it used to exist.

i tried reading the documentation but in vain

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation you have to import the firebase auth package:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

and then use it like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .userChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

so in your case the `auth.` before `FirebaseAuth` is invalid.

[here are the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start)